# What am I missing? RestSharp won't deserialize Json

Tags: c#, json, foursquare, restsharp

I am trying to turn a json response back from foursquare into objects. I get something like this back

```
   {
   "meta":{
      "code":200
   },
   "response":{
      "venues":[
         {
            "id":"4abfb58ef964a520be9120e3",
            "name":"Costco",
            "contact":{
               "phone":"6045967435",
               "formattedPhone":"(604) 596-7435"
            },
            "location":{
               "address":"7423 King George Hwy",
               "crossStreet":"btw 76 Avenue & 73A Avenue",
               "lat":49.138259617056015,
               "lng":-122.84723281860352,
               "distance":19000,
               "postalCode":"V3W 5A8",
               "city":"Surrey",
               "state":"BC",
               "country":"Canada",
               "cc":"CA"
            },
            "canonicalUrl":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/v\/costco\/4abfb58ef964a520be9120e3",
            "categories":[
               {
                  "id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1f6941735",
                  "name":"Department Store",
                  "pluralName":"Department Stores",
                  "shortName":"Department Store",
                  "icon":{
                     "prefix":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/img\/categories_v2\/shops\/departmentstore_",
                     "suffix":".png"
                  },
                  "primary":true
               }
            ],
            "verified":true,
            "restricted":true,
            "stats":{
               "checkinsCount":2038,
               "usersCount":533,
               "tipCount":12
            },
            "url":"http:\/\/www.costco.ca",
            "specials":{
               "count":0,
               "items":[

               ]
            },
            "hereNow":{
               "count":0,
               "groups":[

               ]
            },
            "referralId":"v-1366316196"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I made a class like this

```
 public class Response
    {
        public string Meta { get; set; }
        public List<Venue> Venues { get; set; }
    }

  public class Venue
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Contact Contact { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public string CanonicalUrl { get; set; }
        public Categories Categories { get; set; }
        public bool Verified { get; set; }
    }

 var response = client.Execute<Response>(request);
       var test = response.Data;
```

Yet `Venues` is always null. I am not sure why though.

Comment: chobo2, your json is invalid and missing many commas between fields. So RetSharp is right.

Comment: Assume that json is valid. It is coming from foursquare(it must work....). The problem you are describing was because I copied it from their live tool what apparently strips out the quotes...the request through code has quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to go a level deeper in the JSON response.  One level up from the `venues` property is the `response` property, which is not currently represented in your `Response` class.

You have two ways to solve this.

1) Add another wrapping response object, which contains the missing `response` property

```
// this is the new wrapping object
public class FourSquareResponse
{
    public string Meta { get; set; }
    public VenueResponse Response { get; set; } // previously missing
}

public class VenueResponse
{
    public List<Venue> Venues { get; set; }
}

public class Venue
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public string CanonicalUrl { get; set; }
    public Categories Categories { get; set; }
    public bool Verified { get; set; }
}
```

And executing the request...

```
var request = new RestRequest(uri);
var response = client.Execute<Response>(request);
```

2) Ignore the `meta` property and start parsing at the `response` property.

*As an aside, it looks like the `meta` property of the JSON response might be an HTTP status code.  If it is and you still need it, RestSharp provides that for you as well (see below).

```
public class Response
{
    public string Meta { get; set; }
    public List<Venue> Venues { get; set; }
}

public class Venue
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public string CanonicalUrl { get; set; }
    public Categories Categories { get; set; }
    public bool Verified { get; set; }
}
```

However, this will require telling RestSharp where to start parsing the response.

```
var request = new RestRequest(uri)
{
    RootElement = "response"
};
var response = client.Execute<Response>(request);

// and the HTTP status (if that's what you need)
response.StatusCode
```

Comment: This answer addresses the core issue of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If i am going in right direction then, ur JSON is not `Valid`

```
Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes
```

Get it validated [jsonformatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

[UPDATED]

Valid JSON would be like:-

```
{
"meta": {
    "code": 200
        },
    "notifications": 
        [
            {
                "type": "notificationTray",
                "item": {
            "unreadCount": 0
                }
            }
        ],
    "response": {
    "venues": [
        {
            "id": "4e15d1348877cd5712112a44",
            "name": "The Arena",
    "contact": { },
    "location": {
        "address": "110 Wall Street",
        "lat": 40.70432634495503,
        "lng": -74.0055421062419,
        "distance": 671,
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "country": "United States",
        "cc": "US"
    },
    "canonicalUrl": "https://foursquare.com/v/the-arena/4e15d1348877cd5712112a44",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1e4941735",
            "name": "Campground",
    "pluralName": "Campgrounds",
    "shortName": "Campground",
    "icon": {
            "prefix": "https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/parks_outdoors/campground_",
            "suffix": ".png"
    },
    "primary": true
}
],
"verified": false,
"stats": {
        "checkinsCount": 149,
        "usersCount": 25,
        "tipCount": 4
},
"specials": {
        "count": 0,
        "items": [ ]
},
"hereNow": {
        "count": 0,
        "groups": [ ]
},
"referralId": "v-1366314443"
}         
]
}

}
```

Comment: right but it is valid json. It was that I took the results from their online tool that returns the json back(https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fll%3D40.7,-74%26groceryStoreId%3D4bf58dd8d48988d118951735) what seems to strip away the quotes. I re-posted with what I am getting back in my code.

Answer (score 0):

JSON deserialization to .NET objects is case sensative. Your property names don't match the JSON tags properly, and that is why when you attempt to deserialize, you are getting back NULL.